# Formatting field value (string) as JSON in Flow - Error: The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra '"SampleJSON"'

Tags: visual-workflow, json, formula-field

I'm trying to use flow to format field values into JSON format via formula but am receiving the following error when checking syntax: `The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra '"SampleJSON"'`

Below is the formula format I have tried:

```
'{
    "Name": "' + Custom_object_name__c + '"  
}'
```

Anyone able to successfully format field values into JSON format via Flow? (I've seen it possible via apex)

Update: The following worked

```
'{ ' "Name" : "' + {!CustomObject.Name__c} + '}'
```

TIA

Comment: what does your Flow formula field look like? It needs to use string constants, concatenation operator, and field values

Comment: The formula field is the code block above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid JSON takes the following form -

```
{
    "fieldName": "value"  
}
```

If you are trying to create a JSON String, you need to wrap the JSON object in single quotes

```
'{
    "fieldName": "value"  
}'
```

or escape your double quotes with a backslash

```
"{
    \"fieldName\": \"value\"  
}"
```

If you're trying to add the value from your custom field, you need to concatenate your string and variable.

```
'{
    "Name": "' + Custom_object_name__c + '"  
}'
```

Comment: Thank you.  However it still seems to be returning a syntax error:  `The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error`.  I've updated my formula above.

Comment: Update: The issue seems to be with the double quotes. The single quote worked along with placing all syntax on a single line (originally had line breaks). Thanks!